# Suggesting and approving an edit on own post?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Look at this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/488122). The person has suggested an edit on his own post and also approved it. How is it possible?

Comment: Wild guess: Two different, now merged, accounts.

Comment: @Bart - Oh.. Didn't think that. That's the situation. :)

Comment: @hims056 you are giving my example....

Comment: @AdvaitAmin - Yes I didn't see that case before it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They created another user that then got merged into their main account. Apparently it was heavily used (note the -725 reputation reversal on Jul 19 '12). According to his history, he doesn't have a +2 for the edit, so all is well (who really cares).

Comment: animuson telling right, i have two accounts in the past, i didn't know that but now they both are merged.